# Getting wrong tr id with .closest .attr

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I am reading tables tr id with closest attribute on change but I keep getting wrong values and do not know how to fix.

If I choose the firts the "lower"(16) checkbox, I get the tr id ok and after that the upper one everythins peachy. Now if I do it the other way around I keep only getting the value of the "top"(17) one. My guess is that it is because the class name is the same, but I´m not sure and I can not influence the class name, since it is generated by Datatables.

Could someone take a peek at jquery and tell me what I´m doing wrong.

Thank you for your help.

```
 var a = $(".report_report").change(function() {



    var closestTr = $('.report_report:checkbox:checked').closest('tr').attr('id');
                                                alert(closestTr);
```

This the basic table concept

```
<table class="something">
    <tr id = "17">
    <td>
   <input class="report_report" type = "checkbox">
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id = "16">
    <td>
     <input class="report_report" type = "checkbox">
    </td>
     </tr>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

try

HTML

```
<table class="something">
    <tr id="17">
        <td>
            <input class="report_report" type="checkbox"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="16">
        <td>
            <input class="report_report" type="checkbox"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

### JS

```
 $(".report_report").change(function() {
    alert($(this).closest("tr").attr("id"));

    });
```

### **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vz58n67r/3/)**

IF you want all selected check box with  parent tr  id

```
$(".report_report").change(function () {

    var cheked = $(".report_report").filter(function () {
        return this.checked;
    }).closest("tr").get();
    console.log(cheked);

});
```

NOTE: you html is `invalid` **tr** is not closed

Comment: I checked my demo undefined is not coming ..did you check demo

Comment: Sorry, my bad fixed it

Comment: I know, but I think it has something to do with datatables. I can not generate a exact replica because of that, just symbolic one

Comment: I have tried that way of doing it before but I can not get a value unless I use ".report_report:checkbox:checked"

Comment: @user1054844 what do you need ?

Comment: To find / a way to fix the issue with getting wrong id if checkboxes are not checked in the right order. e.g possibly something related to Datatables own functions

Comment: something similar maybe to this TableTools.fnGetInstance(self.tables.myrows.node) but I cannot use that, because I can not use drawCallback at that point.